# Fuzzy correction of url strings

Tags: search, matching, autocorrect

I'm having thousands of broken strings, and hope to convert them to actual urls. For example, I might be having eycompany as my input string and want to output ey.com. The input can be messier than that in reality(it could also be eynycconsultingcompany), and doesn't follow any patterns. The correction can be fuzzy in nature, it doesn't need to be perfect. Any thoughts on how this should be done?

Comment: Not without knowing the string beforehand. Not easily anyhow.

Comment: show what you have now, in what language do you want to solve this in?

Comment: for example i have hyundai-ubiquitous-information-technology,41-73-230-67-calabar-wib-test, d-1-g-jalan-multimedia-7a. The company name is included in the string but gets mixed with other stuff. Probably solve in python? @BojanPetkovic